# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have a class `RequestValidator` Class which I want to test. This class method `validate()` is taking `RequestData` as method parameter and `RequestData` is my POJO class.

```
package com.ge.health.gam.contactge.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ge.health.gam.common.validate.Validation;
import com.ge.health.gam.common.validate.ValidationResult;
import com.ge.health.gam.common.validate.Validator;
import com.ge.health.gam.contactge.model.RequestData;

@Component
public class RequestValidator implements Validator<RequestData> {

    @Override
    public ValidationResult validate(String objectName, RequestData rqdata) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String regex = "^[0-3]?[0-9]/[0-3]?[0-9]/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2},([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$";

        ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult();

        if (rqdata == null) {
            result.addError("error.invalidObjectGraph", "Object graph not initialized correctly");
            return result;
        }
        Validation.rule("EquipmentId", rqdata.getEquipmentID()).required().run(result);
        Validation.rule("Modality", rqdata.getModality()).required().run(result);
        Validation.rule("FacilityID", rqdata.getFacilityID()).required().run(result);
        Validation.rule("CountryCode", rqdata.getCountryCode()).required().maxLength(3).matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")
                .run(result);
        Validation.rule("ProblemType", rqdata.getProblemType()).required().run(result);
        Validation.rule("Name", rqdata.getName()).required().maxLength(20).run(result);
        Validation.rule("PhoneNumber", rqdata.getPhoneNumber()).required().maxLength(25).matches("[0-9]+").run(result);
        Validation.rule("Extension", rqdata.getExtension()).required().maxLength(10).matches("[0-9]+").run(result);
        Validation.rule("Description", rqdata.getDescription()).required().maxLength(300).run(result);
        Validation.rule("ShortDescription", rqdata.getShortDescription()).required().maxLength(80).run(result);
        Validation.rule("TimePeriod", rqdata.getTimePeriod()).required().matches(regex).run(result);
        Validation.rule("Locale", rqdata.getLocale()).required().run(result);

        System.out.println("value of requesting app is:" + rqdata.getRequestingApp());
        Validation.rule("RequestingApp", rqdata.getRequestingApp()).required().matches("icenter").run(result);
        System.out.println(result.getErrorDetails());
        return result;
    }

}
```

This is my Model class.

```
package com.ge.health.gam.contactge.model;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

public class RequestData {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String equipmentID;
    private String modality;
    private String facilityID;
    private String countryCode;
    private String isoCode;
    private String problemType;
    private String problemArea;
    private String equipmentStatus;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String extension;
    private String description;
    private String shortDescription;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private String timePeriod;
    private String serviceCode;
    private String locale;
    private String requestingApp;
    private String examNumber;
    private String seriesNumber;
    private String imageNumber;

    public String getImageNumber() {
        return imageNumber;
    }

    public void setImageNumber(String imageNumber) {
        this.imageNumber = imageNumber;
    }

    public String getEquipmentID() {
        return equipmentID;
    }

    public void setEquipmentID(String equipmentID) {
        this.equipmentID = equipmentID;
    }

    public String getModality() {
        return modality;
    }

    public void setModality(String modality) {
        this.modality = modality;
    }

    public String getFacilityID() {
        return facilityID;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getIsoCode() {
        return isoCode;
    }

    public void setIsoCode(String isoCode) {
        this.isoCode = isoCode;
    }

    public String getProblemType() {
        return problemType;
    }

    public void setProblemType(String problemType) {
        this.problemType = problemType;
    }

    public String getProblemArea() {
        return problemArea;
    }

    public void setProblemArea(String problemArea) {
        this.problemArea = problemArea;
    }

    public String getEquipmentStatus() {
        return equipmentStatus;
    }

    public void setEquipmentStatus(String equipmentStatus) {
        this.equipmentStatus = equipmentStatus;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public String getTimePeriod() {
        return timePeriod;
    }

    public void setTimePeriod(String timePeriod) {
        this.timePeriod = timePeriod;
    }

    public String getServiceCode() {
        return serviceCode;
    }

    public void setServiceCode(String serviceCode) {
        this.serviceCode = serviceCode;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String getRequestingApp() {
        return requestingApp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("RequestData [equipmentID=").append(equipmentID).append(", modality=").append(modality)
                .append(", facilityID=").append(facilityID).append(", countryCode=").append(countryCode)
                .append(", isoCode=").append(isoCode).append(", problemType=").append(problemType)
                .append(", problemArea=").append(problemArea).append(", equipmentStatus=").append(equipmentStatus)
                .append(", name=").append(name).append(", phoneNumber=").append(phoneNumber).append(", extension=")
                .append(extension).append(", description=").append(description).append(", shortDescription=")
                .append(shortDescription).append(", timePeriod=").append(timePeriod).append(", serviceCode=")
                .append(serviceCode).append(", locale=").append(locale).append(", requestingApp=").append(requestingApp)
                .append(", examNumber=").append(examNumber).append(", seriesNumber=").append(seriesNumber)
                .append(", imageNumber=").append(imageNumber).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public void setRequestingApp(String requestingApp) {
        this.requestingApp = requestingApp;
    }

    public String getExamNumber() {
        return examNumber;
    }

    public void setExamNumber(String examNumber) {
        this.examNumber = examNumber;
    }

    public String getSeriesNumber() {
        return seriesNumber;
    }

    public void setSeriesNumber(String seriesNumber) {
        this.seriesNumber = seriesNumber;
    }

    public void setFacilityID(String facilityID) {
        this.facilityID = facilityID;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

This is my test class.

```
package com.ge.health.gam.contactge.service.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;

import com.ge.health.gam.common.validate.ValidationResult;
import com.ge.health.gam.contactge.model.RequestData;
import com.ge.health.gam.contactge.service.RequestValidator;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class RequestValidatorTest {

    RequestValidator reqValidator = new RequestValidator();;

    @Mock
    RequestData reqData;

    @Mock
    ValidationResult validateResult;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Throwable {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    @PowerMockIgnore
    public void testValidate() {
        SimplePojo pojo = new SimplePojo();
        pojo.setCountryCode("123");
        pojo.setEquipmentID("414541HD01");
        pojo.setModality("sjdksd");
        pojo.setFacilityID("sdjhsdj");
        pojo.setCountryCode("CA");
        pojo.setIsoCode("2");
        pojo.setProblemType("ddddddddd");
        pojo.setProblemArea("ssbnc");
        pojo.setEquipmentStatus("sdsds");
        pojo.setName("pinku");
        pojo.setPhoneNumber("2999999999992");
        pojo.setExtension("dnbsd");
        pojo.setDescription("sdsjd");
        pojo.setShortDescription("sjdks");
        pojo.setTimePeriod("01/01/2011,13:00");
        pojo.setLocale("en_US");

        pojo.setRequestingApp("icenter");

        when(reqData.getCountryCode()).thenReturn("CA");

        Assert.assertEquals(true, reqValidator.validate("priyanka", pojo));
        Assert.assertEquals("CA", reqData.getCountryCode());

    }

    class SimplePojo extends RequestData {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    }

}
```

I am getting this error while running `jUnit` test case

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability;
>             at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:26)
>             at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:21)
>             at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:167)
>             at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:161)
>             at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:54)
>             at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1449)

Comment: Why do you mock `RequestData reqData`?  It is just a pojo. Why do you mock `ValidationResult validateResult`? it is not used in test. I don't think you need mockito in your test.

Comment: This isn't due to mismatched versions of Mockito and PowerMockito on your claspath by any chance?

Comment: ya in my maven dependency both slf4j and log4j was there so they were conflictig each other now i removed one now its working.